# Location of project.properties file in Android Studio 0.6.1

Tags: android-studio, proguard

I am studying how to use ProGuard but I could not find the project.properties file on my project. Was that replaced? I can see a proguard-rules.pro.  But I could not find the line where I have to remove the comment #.

So far, this is what I have done. I change the false to true in runProguard and change the proguardFiles to "proguard-android-optimize".

```
  apply plugin: 'android'

   android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tok.advertisement"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project properties has been replaced in the transition to the Gradle system. 
ProGuard in Gradle:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard

Comment: `project.properties` is replaced with what file? Now, which file is same to `project.properties`?

Comment: Everything is done with build.gradle now (be sure you're looking at the right one, there are two per project) as far as importing libraries and setting version numbers, properties, etc.

local.properties handles the sdk location.